# IOS UI notification bar Transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have an `imageView` at the top of my page.

I want to use a transition like the one similar to default scroll of `notification bar` in iPhone on dragging my `imageView`.

Can anyone help me to create similar transition?

Comment: Don't understand which transition you're talking about here. Please provide some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inorder to achieve the iOS Notification like transition,you just need to modify code in https://github.com/crocodella/PullableView in your desired way.